# How do you restore an RDS aurora snapshot using ansibleR

Tags: ansible, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to create a clone of an Aurora database from a snapshot using ansible. I'm using the rds_snapshot_facts and rds_instance modules since the rds module doesn't support Aurora. This is the playbook I have (with region/profile removed). When I run it it fails with

> Unable to restore DB instance from DB snapshot: An error occurred (DBSnapshotNotFound) when calling the RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot operation: DBSnapshot not found: *snapshot id*

Has anyone managed to restore a snapshot like this using the rds_instance module, since it's status is preview I'm not sure if this functions properly yet.

```
---                                   
- hosts: localhost              
  connection: local                                             
  tasks:                                                          
    - name: Get rds snapshots            
      rds_snapshot_facts:                                                    
          db_cluster_identifier: "{{rds_live_instance}}"
      register: rds_snapshot                          
    - name: Create dev db                                   
      rds_instance:                             
          wait: yes                       
          vpc_security_group_ids:                 
            - "{{rds_security_group}}"    
          storage_encrypted: yes
          publicly_accessible: no      
          engine: aurora-mysql
          db_subnet_group_name: default
          id: "dev-{{branch}}"
          cluster_id: "dev-{{branch}}-cluster"
          creation_source: snapshot                                
          availability_zone: eu-west-1a
          auto_minor_version_upgrade: yes        
          allow_major_version_upgrade: no
          db_snapshot_identifier: "{{item.db_cluster_snapshot_identifier}}"
          snapshot_identifier: "{{item.db_cluster_snapshot_arn}}"
      with_items:                            
        - "{{rds_snapshot.cluster_snapshots | last }}"
```

Comment: Is there anything else you'd like as part of this post?

Comment: I'll need to debug ansible with your answer before I know if your solution helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ansible I used shell module + AWS CLI
Restoring cluster from snapshot

```
- name: Restore Aurora DB cluster from snapshot
  shell: | 
    aws rds restore-db-cluster-from-snapshot \
      --db-cluster-identifier {{ aurora_cluster_name }} \
      --snapshot-identifier {{ db_cluster_snapshot_arn }} \
      --db-subnet-group-name {{ subnet_group_name }} \
      --engine aurora-postgresql \
      --region {{ region }}
```

Empty cluster is created. Then add instances to cluster using rds_instance module

```
- name: Add Aurora DB instance to cluster
  rds_instance:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    engine: aurora-postgresql
    db_instance_identifier: "{{ aurora_cluster_name }}-instance"
    instance_type: db.t3.medium
    cluster_id: "{{ aurora_cluster_name }}"
    db_subnet_group_name: "{{ subnet_group_name }}"
    wait: yes
```

Don't forget about idempotency and check first, if cluster already exists.

Comment: Yep that's the best I can come up with too, and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with Ansible, but looking at your error, you seem to be calling `RestoreDBInstance*` api, which DOES NOT work with cluster based engines like Aurora. You should be calling `RestoreDBCluster*` version and that would create a new cluster for you. You'd then need to add an instance to the cluster using `CreateDbInstance` Api.

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to wire this up in Ansible. Hope this helps!